# Connect 4 Game logic

Tags: python, tkinter

am developing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four game in python using tkinter.

I have come up with the board and the two player pieces. I am now trying to check if the game is over. I have implemented the following logic, but this doesnt seem to work.

```
def checkWin():
        for row in range(canvas.data.rows):
            for col in range(canvas.data.cols):
                checkWinFromCell(row, col)

def checkWinFromCell(row, col):
        if canvas.data.board[row][col] == 0:
            return False
        dirs = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [1,-1], [0,-1], [-1,0], [-1,-1], [-1,1]]
        for direction in dirs:
            checkWinFromCellInDir(row, col, direction)
        return False

def checkWinFromCellInDir(row, col, direction):
        drow, dcol = direction[0], direction[1]
        for i in range(1,4):
            if row+i*drow<0 or row+i*drow>=canvas.data.rows or col+i*dcol<0 or col+i*dcol>=canvas.data.cols:
                return False
            if canvas.data.board[row][col] != canvas.data.board[row+i*drow][col+i*dcol]:
                return False
        return canvas.data.board[row][col]
```

I need to know the logic to check if my game has been completed ie the four dots have been connected.

Comment: What do you mean "but this doesnt seem to work". What specifically doesn't work? Also please consider reducing your code down to the bit that doesn't work. Posting irrelevant code is a sure fire way to get your question down voted.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify on you.

Comment: You really need to comment your code =/

Comment: You never `return True`. This code can never return `True`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Tkinter, so this is a halfhearted answer at best. However since it's been nearly an hour and no answer is forthcoming, I did work one up for you.

```
class Map(list):
    def __init__(self, tiles, width, height):
        """This object functions exactly as a tile map for your connect four
        game. It is a subclass of list, so you can iterate through its rows.
        "y" increases from top to bottom and "x" increases from left to right"""
        for y in range(height):
            self.append([random.choice(tiles) for x in range(width)])
            # for ease of use, we're generating a random tile map here
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([' '.join([ch for ch in row]) for row in self])
        # this will make print(map_object) show something pretty

Vector = collections.namedtuple("Vector", ['x','y'])
# build a namedtuple to contain our directions. It's a bit easier on the eyes
# to use object access, IMO. YMMV.

def checkwin(map_):
    directions = [Vector(x, y) for (x, y) in [(1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]]
    # directions = E, SW, S, SE
    for y, row in enumerate(map_):
        for x, ch in enumerate(row):
            value = ch
            if value == ' ': continue # blank squares can't win
            for vector in directions:
                result = checkfour(map_, x, y, vector)
                if result:
                    return result
            return False

def checkfour(map_, x, y, vector):
    """Checks map_ for four squares from the given x and y in vector direction"""
    value = map_[y][x]
    try:
        lst = [map_[y + k*vector.y][x + k*vector.x]==value for k in range(1,4)]
        # 2 2 2 1 would return [True, True, False]
        return all(lst) and (x,y)
    except IndexError:
        return False
        # we know we'll run off the edge of the map. It's cheaper (in programmer
        # time) to simply return False here rather than check each square to make
        # sure there ARE 3 more squares in vector-direction.

map_ = Map("12 ", 8, 8)
print(checkwin(map_))
# if your randomly generated map would win in connect four, it should print
# the first (x,y) coordinate that begins a win going E, SW, S, or SE
print(map_)
```

Comment: Assuming your code works, nice job. Hopefully it will get the poster an A+ in their assignment.

Comment: @MattCoubrough I've tested all the bits and pieces, but I re-wrote and didn't copy-paste here so it's possible I introduced a few bugs along the way. I actually doubt this is a school project, though I suppose it's possible! :)

Comment: Yeah it looks like a complete re-write from scratch. The comments may even get them extra merit.

Comment: @MattCoubrough it was a complete re-write. As I mentioned: I'm not really familiar with Tkinter so I can't use its canvas model to test against. I built the `Map` class instead and worked against that instead. Seemed silly to try and change or even "fix" OPs code if I'm tearing out its foundation. What I meant is that I doubt that OP is doing this for a school project -- it looks like a personal endeavor to me. Maybe I just have strange ways of spending my free time :D